# How can i make my Android application connect to a particular single wifi before you can have access to some pages using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, wifimanager, ssid

So i'm working on an Android application that should use WiFi to determine if a user was within a certain building and allow them to check-in....

Is it possible to only allow users to checkin once a particular Wifi network is detected instead? I would like to do this because we are in a building where I will like users of the app to  access only one of the establment's WiFi, via its ssid before they can checkin/signin on the app...

Any thoughts on how to achieve this on kotlin  please?
I have tried to implement this though but not working:

```
    Private fun conWifi(context: Context){
    val wifiManager: WifiManager = context.applicationcontext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
    val wifiInfo: WifiInfo! = wifiManager.conectionInfo

   if (wifiInfo.ssid.equals("SamsungWifi")){

           // some codes like show another page

       }

       else{

          // Toast...
       }

    }
```

Then I called it on:

```
enter.setonClickListener() {it: View!

     conWifi(applicationContext)

}
```

Please don't be offended I typed with a phone, please someone should help me and format, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo#getSSID()):

> If the SSID can be decoded as UTF-8, it will be returned surrounded by double quotation marks. Otherwise, it is returned as a string of hex digits. The SSID may be `WifiManager#UNKNOWN_SSID`, if there is no network currently connected or if the caller has insufficient permissions to access the SSID.
>
> Prior to `Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1`, this method always returned the SSID with no quotes around it.

Maybe you want to check the double quotation marks.

Comment: That's not what my question pointed to, I want the app to display the next activity if the wifiInfo.ssid == "SamsungWifi" else then it will return a taost like an error message, so it will remain in that activity.

Comment: @oriohac The explain what exactly do you mean by "not working", can't login at all even on the correct SSID? Or the reverse, still able to login even on incorrect SSID, or if you get an exception etc

Comment: I mean when the user is connected to only "SamsungWifi" which I want to take as an instance to be the office WiFi then the person can proceed to the next page to signin, but it is not working I need someone to help me out, because it is only the Toast message that is coming up, the if() block is not working, so that if someone is signed into the WiFi then he/she can have access to other parts of the app.

Comment: What's the value of `wifiInfo.ssid` when you connect to a WiFi?

Comment: @oriohac What the documentation implies is that you should check for `"\"SamsungWifi\""`, in addition to just `"SamsungWifi"`.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov thank you Very much I used "\" SamsungWifi \"", and it worked, instead of just "SamsungWifi", please what is the secret behind it, what's the reason for the  backward slashes. Thank you everyone for your contributions, I really appreciate that.

Comment: @oriohac `\"` is how you write a `"` character _inside_ a string literal `"..."`, because if you wrote just `"` it would end the string.

Comment: Alright please a follow up question, when the if() block is checked and returned true, that means it is connected to the WiFi with ssid "\" SamsungWifi\"" that is on the first launch of the app, after then it just goes straight to the body of the code without checking the if() block like the WiFi ssid is saved in memory or something, even when I try wifiManager.isEnabled, it just checks if WiFi is enabled and continue to the body not minding if it is connected to "\" SamsungWifi\"" , please is there function to check if a user is connected to a particular WiFi, just like the .isEnabled?